# In Xdebug v3 if I change a breakpoint while step debugging I get nginx 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: xdebug

I'm running PHP 7.4 in Docker. I am able to step debug just fine, however, unlike in Xdebug v2 if I add a breakpoint or remove a breakpoint while step debugging I am getting a 502 Bad Gateway message from nginx and the step debugging session just dies.

Am I missing a setting for Xdebug v3 in order to set new breakpoints or remove breakpoints while step debugging without killing the session?

**php.ini settings**

```
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=true
xdebug.max_nesting_level=1500
```

**Environment variable for Xdebug session set in docker:**

```
XDEBUG_SESSION: docker
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Xdebug issue: https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1897 (https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1899 is a duplicate of that).

Says fixed for next Xdebug v3.0.1 (you can build from sources if you can and need it now).

**UPDATE 2020-12-04:** Xdebug 3.0.1 has been released.

Comment: Yes, and here's the fix in 3.0.1 when it is released.

https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/commit/4fdd4caa7dda4bea5b928487456f396caefdd893